# How to check if url path/pathname exists (Node.js URL)

Tags: node.js, node-modules, urlparse

I am using node.js URL lib https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/url.html

Now in my particular case I'm receiving urls that may or may not contain paths.

e.g.

1. http://www.google.com/
2. http://www.google.com

What suprises me is that when I parse the (2.) url

```
const parsedUrl = Url.parse('httpp://www.google.com')
```

The returning object looks like this:

```
Url {
  protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true,
  auth: null,
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: null,
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/',
  path: '/',
  href: 'http://www.google.com/'
}
```

So in this case I'm expecting the `path` or `pathname` should be null, but they are not.
Is there way to check whether the path/pathname should be set or not.

Because for my purposes I want to return `return host + path`
But since path is at least = '/' I am not sure how to manage this.

Comment: It is supposed to happen. In `https://www.google.com`, the path is `/`.

Comment: Ok, coming from a python background this works quite different from what I am used to. So this literally means that there is no way to tell the difference, if not parsing the raw url.

Comment: Why would you want to tell the difference? The request made to the server will be exactly the same with both URLs.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but @D.Pardal you are indeed right. I think in my particular case I was working with a library that was rather accepting invalid URLs. Thanks for the help